# Cucumber-eclipse-maven- project

Tags: eclipse, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd

I have a question and I have been looking for a lot of reviews and nothing seems to work.

I am trying to run my project in my mac.

And always than I put in my cucumber file for example:

example:

[image]

---

only the line where I use "<>" show the next message : "step does not have a matching glue code.

and I totally sure that the same name is connected with his method in my page objects.

The weird thing is that in my windows computer the project run perfectly. I don't know why occurs this.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Could you please upload the code for the tests, or link to a repo if too big?

Comment: Could you please share us your cucumberOptions?